# Install separate+ gimp plugin on fedora

Tags: plugins, gimp

I tried to build the separate+ plugin (http://cue.yellowmagic.info/softwares/separate-plus/) on fedora, but got several error messages when trying to make it from source.

> Package gtk+-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gtk+-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>
> No package 'gtk+-2.0' found
>   Package gimp-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
>   Perhaps you should add the directory containing `gimp-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
>   No package 'gimp-2.0' found

etc.

Any hints about which packages I need?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After some resesarch these are the things I had to do on my fedora machine.

Install following packages to get the missing dependencies:

```
sudo dnf install gtk2-devel

sudo dnf install gimp-devel

(sudo dnf install lcms) - i think that step was not needed

(export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib) - i think this was also unnecessary

sudo dnf install lcms-devel

sudo dnf install libtiff-devel

sudo dnf install libjpeg-devel

export LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -lm"

make
```

Finally, copy the build executables to the .gimp-2.8/plug-ins/ directory